# What can I do about my kaputt posterous site?

Tags: photos, blogging

I have a posterous photoblog here: http://montereyscenics.posterous.com/ that is still reachable, but no longer displays the photos; also, most of my archives seem to be missing. At first I thought it was just a temporary glitch, but it's been a few days now. I tried to see where I could contact the webmaster about what's going on, and to apprise them of the woeful state of my site (perhaps they're not aware of it, or perhaps they are and it's a widespread problem they're working on? I don't know).

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to contact the Posterousians about this?

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for Super User (not about computer software or hardware). That being said, I can see your photos just fine. For support, since I can't find any useful link on their website and they have been acquired by Twitter, I'd try the [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a contact support link here: http://posterous.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/topics/5674-advanced (look for the envelope icon).

It opens a window where you can submit a form.  I have no idea of how often they check form submissions.

~ And there are 7 pages of scenic photos at that link you gave.

Answer (score 1):

According to their [whois](http://www.who.is/whois/posterous.com) record, their admin and technical contact is Sachin Agarwal admin@posterous-inc.com.